# SQL re-initialize value after some time

Tags: sql, database, initialization

1. Summary

*I want to prevent a user to launch two processes at the same time.
Basically I would like to update a value on a SQL database that automatically "re-initializes" after some time.*

2. Description

Here, the action triggers some calculations (performed on a server) and the results are displayed on a chart on the web page. It takes about 10 minutes for all points to be displayed on the chart.

Possible actions and limitations: What I can do is to assign a value (say **process**) to each user.
When the user starts to launch the process, I check **process**.
If **process** is 0, then I allow the user to launch and I then update **process** to 1 on the SQL database. At the end of the process (say after 10 minutes), I set  **process** to 0.

This works fine but if the user closes the page before the end of the process (before 10 minutes), then the value **process** remains at 1 and so the user cannot launch a new process.

3. Summary

   How to update a value on a SQL database that automatically "re-initializes" after some time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store the time when the user launched the action too. You can then use that information when a new process is required:

```
create table users (
    user_id int primary key,
    ... -- other columns as needed
    in_progress int,
    launched_at datetime
);
```

When a user wants to launch a process, you run the following query:

```
update users
set in_progress = 1, launched_at = now()
where 
    in_progress = 0
    or (launched_at is null or launched_at < now() - interval 10 minute)
```

This allows users to start the process only if no process is in progress, or if no process was launched within the last 10 minutes.

If the query affects no rows, then you know some of the condition was not met - so basically the user is not allowed to launch a new process now.